# Recursive copy without overwrite

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, merge, ecmascript-6

I have data that looks like this:

```
`+---------------+-------+
| groups_field | value |
+---------------+-------+
| 1-1           |     2 |
| 1-2-1         |     4 |
| 2-1           |     3 |
| 2-2-4         |     8 |
+---------------+-------+`
```

I want this data into a multi-dimensional object array, that looks like this:

```
`groups: [{
   id: 1,
   fields: [{
      id: 1,
      value: 2
   }], 
   groups: [{
      id: 2, 
      fields: [{
         id: 1,
         value: 4
       }]
   }]
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    fields: [{
       id: 1,
       value: 3
    }],
    groups: [{
       id: 2,
       fields: [{
          id: 4,
          value: 8
       }]
     }]
}]`
```

I have figured out how to get mostly there with reduceRight:

```
let gfArray = row.groups_field.split('-')
let newRow = gfArray.reduceRight((obj, key, index) => {
  var a = {}
  if (index === gfArray.length - 1) {
    a = {id: key, value: row.value}
  } else if (index === gfArray.length - 2) {
    a.fields = [obj]
    a.id = key
  } else if (index === 0) {
    a.groups = obj
    a.id = key
  } else {
    a.id = key
    a.groups = [obj]
  }
  return a
}, {})
product_data.push(newRow)
```

which gives me this:

```
`groups: [{
   id: 1,
   fields: [{
      id: 1,
      value: 2
   }]
 },
{
   id: 1,
   groups: [{
      id: 2, 
      fields: [{
         id: 1,
         value: 4
       }]
   }]
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    fields: [{
       id: 1,
       value: 3
    }]
 },
 {
    id: 2,
    groups: [{
       id: 2,
       fields: [{
          id: 4,
          value: 8
       }]
     }]
 }]`
```

So is there a way to merge these objects recursively, since the number of groups is dynamic, so that a level has groups or fields, its not overwritten, but is "push" into the array? Or is there even a simpler way to convert my string list of groups and a field to a multi-dimensional object array.

I also will need to add a name prop to each level, for each group and field, I could do that after with another recursive function... I think.

FYI, I'm using this inside of Vuejs so es6 js, is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your original data is this:

```
 const rows = [{
   groups_field: "1-1",
   value: 2
 },
 // ...
];
```

So now we need a root object we can append the data to and a nested hashtable for faster searching:

```
 const root = { groups: [], fields: [] };
 const hash = { _:root };
```

Now lets go over the entries:

```
for(const {groups_field, value} of rows){
```

To get the *fields* and *groups* we need to split up the groups field:

```
 const groups = groups_field.split("-");
 const field = groups.pop();
```

Now the black magic: We go down our nested hashtable and create the tree paths that don't exist yet:

```
 let path = hash;
 for(const id of groups){
  // If the entry does not exist in the hashtable yet:
  if(!path[id]){
   // Create a new entry
   const el = {
     id,
     groups:[],
     fields: []
   };
   // Add a new path to the nested hashtable containing the new entry as an exit
   path[id] = { _: el };
   // Add the entry to the groups
   path._.groups.push(el);
 }
 // Go dow one level in the hashtable:
 path = path[id];
}
```

Now finally we only need to add the field:

```
path._.fields.push({ id: field, fields: value });
```

And now root contains the desired result...

Note: `_` is the hashtables exit node identifier. Using a `Symbol` would be definetly more elegant, but i left it away for clarity.

Comment: If you dont understand how it works, please `console.log(hash)` first, and feel free to ask ;)

Comment: Looks promising! But I'm getting this error in my console "Cannot read prop push of 'undefined'" for this line: path._.groups.push(el)...

Comment: @blalan yes there was an error in the first version of my code, make shure that `const root = { groups: [], fields:[] }`

Comment: Ah, I see the update now. It's perfect and beautiful. Thank you for your quick work!